# How to check resources consumption sort by websites in Linux Debian server?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, debian-wheezy

I have apache2 installed on Linux Debian VPS. How can I check how much *RAM* or *CPU* consumes particular website? When I run **HTOP** I see just in *user* col value *"www-data"* and in *command* col value *"user/sbin/apache2"* and I don't know which website pressures on processor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your websites are running under same (default) user, then there is no way to see which specific user/script is hitting your server hard.

You should use different approach in this situation. I would suggest to use two tools that mimic 'top', but read (and calculate) their data from apache logs.

First tool is called apachetop, and it will show you requests per second. It accepts path to apache access or combined log format file:

```
apachetop -f /var/log/apache2/access.log -r 1
```

You can repeat -f argument as many times as you wish (as many access_logs you have - if you use different ones per each vhost).

Program will output top-like interface with request URIs at the top being hit the most times. If you press '?' you'll get various other options.

This won't directly answer your question, but it can help you pinpoint which URIs are being accessed the most.

Other than that you can use GoAccess, to analyze access_logs and compare them, or write your own script which will calculate statistics in the last hour for example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It helped me to realize that I should set up separate user per installed website.